# Converting Dijkstra's Algorithm from Python3 to CircuitPython (TI-Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm writing Python code on one of the new TI-84 Python edition calculators. These use a version of CircuitPython with limited support for some quite basic features.

This includes missing dictionary methods such as `items()` and `values()`.

My original version of Dijkstra's Algorithm is below, followed by a nearly complete version in TI-Python. I'm having trouble converting the final two `items()` instances with working alternatives.

```
nodes = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
distances = {
    'A': {'B': 6, 'D': 1},
    'B': {'A': 6, 'C': 5, 'D': 2, 'E' :2},
    'C': {'B': 5, 'E': 5},
    'D': {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'E': 1},
    'E': {'B': 2, 'C': 5, 'D': 1}}


unvisited = {node: None for node in nodes} #using None as +inf
visited = {}
current = 'A' # the start node
currentDistance = 0
unvisited[current] = currentDistance

while True:
    # for the nodes adjacent to the current node.
    for neighbour, distance in distances[current].items():
        # ignore if already visited
        if neighbour not in unvisited:
            continue
        # calculate the total distance to this new node
        newDistance = currentDistance + distance
        # if this adjacent node has a lower distance
        if unvisited[neighbour] is None or unvisited[neighbour] > newDistance:
            # update distance to this new, lower distance
            unvisited[neighbour] = newDistance
    # add current node and distance from start to visited list
    visited[current] = currentDistance
    # Remove current node from unvisited list
    del unvisited[current]
    # if all nodes have been visited
    if not unvisited:
        # exit
        break
    # candidates for next node to visit
    print(unvisited.items())
        # print(node[1])
    candidates = [node for node in unvisited.items() if node[1]]
    print(candidates)
    current, currentDistance = sorted(candidates, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]

# print(visited)

print(dict(sorted(visited.items())))
```

TI-Python version:

```
ns = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
ds = {
    "A": {"B": 6, "D": 1},
    "B": {"A": 6, "C": 5, "D": 2, "E": 2},
    "C": {"B": 5, "E": 5},
    "D": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "E": 1},
    "E": {"B": 2, "C": 5, "D": 1}
}

un = {no: None for no in ns}
vi = {}
cn = "A"
cd = 0
un[cn] = cd

while True:
    for ne in sorted(ds[cn]):
        di = ds[cn][ne]
        if ne not in un:
            continue
        nd = cd + di
        if un[ne] is None or un[ne] > nd:
            un[ne] = nd
    vi[cn] = cd
    del un[cn]
    if not un:
        break
    cs = [no for no in un.items() if no[1]]
    cn, cd = sorted(cs, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

print(dict(sorted(vi.items())))
```

Could someone please explain how to refactor `cs = [no for no in un.items() if no[1]]` and `print(dict(sorted(vi.items())))` so they don't need the `.items()` or `.values()`. methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst `.items()` is very useful, it is equivalent to iterating the keys and then looking up the value.

```py
for k in dict:
    v = dict[k]
```

is equivalent to

```py
for k, v in dict.items():
```

Thus a crude refactor of

```py
cs = [no for no in un.items() if no[1]]
```

Would be:

```py
cs = [[k, un[k]] for k in un if un[k]]
```

Note that the original could be better written as:

```py
cs = [[k,v] for k, v in un.items() if v]
```

Likewise,

```py
print(dict(sorted(vi.items())))
```

is directly equivalent to:

```py
print(dict(sorted([k, vi[k] for k in vi]))
```

but that's not very readable IMHO.  I would do:

```py
print({k: vi[k] for k in sorted(vi.keys()})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I use `cs = [k for k in un if un[k]]`, `cn, cd = sorted(cs, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]` gives `IndexError: string index out of range` any idea why please?

Comment: yes! I made a very stupid error. See the updated answer